# My django admin search list page view distorted

Tags: python, css, django, admin

Is anyone know how to fix this css issue getting distorted see screenshot

[this is the screenshot of distorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl4tf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + f5 do hard refresh webpage sometimes cookies/cache of css overwrited

Comment: Not working i did it already